# Rails—Migrate a table (with data) to have UUID instead of ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I have a `Project` model, which has dependents, and there are already records in the db.

I want to change `Project.id` (it's primary key) to be a UUID, instead of just an incrementing integer.

How do I write a migration that will change the id, update existing records to have UUID, and update their references in other tables' foreign keys?

Answer (score -1):

To migrate from default `id` to use `uuid`, try writing migration like this:

```
class ChangeProjectsPrimaryKey < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :uuid, :uuid, default: "uuid_generate_v4()", null: false

    change_table :projects do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end

    execute "ALTER TABLE projects ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end
end
```

Comment: First of all this migration has no extension to use uuid; second, it is irreversible; third, it cant work when referenced data exist